# SCons with partially generated source files and variant builds: how to set up dependencies properly

Tags: python, c++, scons

I am facing a weird SCons problem although it does not look like I am trying to achieve anything weird. Here is the situation (unfortunately, we use many proprietary SCons wrappers so I am not sure any code samples can explain much):

file `scons.1`:

```
cpp_list = env.MyGenerator(meta_sources,arguments)

for variant in variants:
    SConscript('scons.2', exports=[env, cpp_list],
               variant_dir=variant, duplicate=0)
```

file `scons.2`:

```
env.MySharedLibrary('foo', [ 'a.cpp', 'b.cpp'] + cpp_list, 
                    extra_compile_build_args)
```

1. File scons.1 calls a generator wrapper function. It gets names of parameter files and returns a list of generated SCons.Node.FS.File objects.
2. Then, scons.1 calls a subsidiary SConscript scons.2 with variant_dir (duplicate=0). The list of generated File objects is passed as an exported parameter.
3. The intention is to build variants of a shared library, and each variant is successfully built in its specific subfolder (the variant directory).
4. There are particular attitude to the generated files though

   - They are generated once and to the parent folder (all variant subdirectories are located in this folder). We prefer to generate them once to be sure all variants use the same generated sources.
   - We do not want them to be compiled once though because variant builds may use different defines and thus the object files should come out obviously different even if the sources are same.
   - This means we generate some files, we need them to be a part of the library build and we need their object files in the variant directory for every build variant.

Surprisingly, this is something I cannot achieve for a very long time because I cannot keep the SCons logic consistent.

The simplest consistent way is to feed the list of generates Files as sources of the library (like in the example). This looks working fine from the dependencies perspective; SCons recognizes when the generated files get updated and thus recompiles them and relinks the libraries. The problem is that SCons puts the resulting objects of the generated files to the parent directory where the generated files are located. Thus, they are not per-variant object files that makes the resulting binaries broken.

Nevertheless, I could not find any way to build separate copies of the object files of the generated files. If I copy the generated files to the variant directories in the parent SConscript (Command(,,(Copy))), SCons can copy the files before they are generated again. If I try to populate the generated files in the subsidiary SConscript, the library builder does not recognize updates of these source files and does not recompile them.

I tried a lot of various options and explicit dependencies but the build chain of dependencies between the files does not look deterministic in different build scenarios. I would truly appreciate any fresh ideas. That's not a question of what functionality SCons has but rather how to bind the functionality together to reach the goal. Till now, I have not found a way but I hardly can believe my situation is too special.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your variant dir SConscript looks something like this

```
Import(['env','list_of_generated_files'])
env.SharedLibary('magically_delicious',list_of_generated_files)
```

Assuming that's the case, here's what SCons is doing under the hood.

1. SharedLibary's only valid source files are object files, shared libraries, and static libraries (I'm fairly certain). And most definitely C/C++ source files are not valid source files. But SCons knows how to build a C/C++ file into an object file.
2. Under the hood SCons does something like this:

   list_of_objects=[env.SharedObject(s) for s in list_of_generated_files]

Since the generated files are in the parent directory, and by default (in other words when no explicit target is specified), SCons will always build the target file next to the specified source file.

Thus yielding your libary in the variant dir, and the objects in the parent dir.

So how do we fix this?
We basically reproduce what SCons is doing under the hood, but this time we specify the target.

```
Import(['env','list_of_generated_files'])
list_of_objects = [env.SharedObject('./${SOURCE.filebase}$SHOBJSUFFIX',s) for s in list_of_generated_files]
env.SharedLibary('magically_delicious',list_of_objects)
```

Notice that you can use subst()'d strings in the target file specification.

Here's a bunch of such examples

```
$TARGET              => sub/dir/file.x
${TARGET.base}       => sub/dir/file
${TARGET.dir}        => sub/dir
${TARGET.file}       => file.x
${TARGET.filebase}   => file
${TARGET.suffix}     => .x
${TARGET.abspath}    => /top/dir/sub/dir/file.x
${TARGET.relpath}    => sub/dir/file.x

$TARGET              => ../dir2/file.x
${TARGET.abspath}    => /top/dir2/file.x
${TARGET.relpath}    => ../dir2/file.x
```

You can read more about such in the [manpage](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html)
Try the above and let us know if this does the trick for you

Comment: To @bdbaddog: Your assumptions are mostly correct. Unfortunately, some build wrappers are involved that breaks the schema. It's more like `env.MySharedLibary('magically_delicious',list_of_sources, extra_flags)` Adding the assumed list_of_objects to the list_of_sources **does work** but object files in the list_of_objects are generated without the extra flags that MySharedLibrary gets. Thus the objects are broken. Obviously, I am trying to avoid creating of code with many duplications and complications.

Comment: @Mtm3.14 I think it would be more productive if you included in the question a short example of what you're trying to do, instead of having us guess how your code looks. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Mtm3.14 - They try moving the build each object explicilty into your MySharedLibrary() (Assuming that's a pseudo builder?)

Comment: Seems likely you could create a simple reproducer with a few dirs and a few files..

Comment: :@Piotr As a said some custom wrappers are involved so not sure an example would help much but:

Comment: @Piotr 
-----------------------------<br/>
#scons.1<br/>
cpp_list = env.MyGenerator(meta_sources,arguments)<br/>
for variant in variants:<br/>
    SConscript('scons.2', exports=[env, cpp_list], variant_dir=variant, duplicate=0)<br/>
-----------------------------<br/>
#scons.2<br/>
env.MySharedLibrary('foo', [ 'a.cpp', 'b.cpp'] + cpp_list, extra_compile_build_args)<br/>

Comment: @Mtm3.14 - please add this code snipped to your original questoin. Formatting will be much easier to read.